# $X_i \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$, and for $\varepsilon >0$, $P(|X_{(n)}-1|\geq \varepsilon) =(1-\varepsilon)^n$. Must we bound $\varepsilon$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$ are iid random variables and we define $X_{(n)} = \max X_i$ as the largest order statistic. I would like to show that $X_{(n)}$ converges in probability to $1$. To do so, I have:

For all $\varepsilon >0$,

$$
P(|X_{(n)}-1|\geq \varepsilon) = \prod_{i} P(X_i <1-\varepsilon) = (1-\varepsilon)^n
$$

Now, to take the limit, I have an issue in that for $0<\varepsilon \leq 1$, as $n \to \infty$, $P(|X_{(n)}-1|\geq \varepsilon)\to 0$. But for $\varepsilon >1$, it blows up. **What is the correct way of doing this problem here**? Is there a bound on $\varepsilon$?

Would it be valid to write:

$$
P(X_{(n)}\leq 1-\varepsilon) = P(X_{(n)}\leq 1-\varepsilon)\mathbb{1}_{\varepsilon>1} + P(X_{(n)}\leq 1-\varepsilon) \mathbb{1}_{\varepsilon\leq 1} \text{ ?}
$$

Comment: why do you need the case $\epsilon >1$? The convergence means that for any _arbitrary small_ $\epsilon >0$ the probability of deviation $|X_{(n)}-1|$ is even smaller.

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache I understand we don't need it, but by definition it says that $\epsilon>0$, and so I am trying to see formally how we can resolve $\epsilon>1$ cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\epsilon \gt 1$ and using $X_i \in [0,1]$ for all $i$, you have:

- $P(|X_{(n)}-1|\geq \epsilon) = 0$ since $-1 \le X_{(n)}-1 \le 0$ and $\epsilon \gt 1$
- $\displaystyle \prod_{i} P(X_i <1-\epsilon) = 0$ since  $0 \le X_i \le 1$ and $1-\epsilon \lt 0$
- $(1-\epsilon)^n \not = 0$ since  $1-\epsilon \lt 0$

so your second equality is incorrect when $\epsilon \gt 1$, but it does not affect your convergence since you know that in this case $P(|X_{(n)}-1|\geq \epsilon) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

The support of $X_i$ is $[0,1]$ therefore $1-X_i \in [0,1]$ so for $\epsilon>1$ your probability is zero.

Comment: How can I formally write out the fact it is probability zero above? Do I condition, use indicators, etc?

Comment: $|X_{(n)} - 1| = 1 - X_{(n)} $ is a value in $[0,1]$. The probability that this value is bigger than one is zero i.e. the probability that $1 - X_{(n)} \ge \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>1$ is zero

Comment: @user321627 I would like to formalize in mathematical notation what you just said, is this valid? $P(X_{(n)}\leq 1-\epsilon) = P(X_{(n)}\leq 1-\epsilon)\mathbb{1}_{\epsilon>1} + P(X_{(n)}\leq 1-\epsilon)\mathbb{1}_{\epsilon\leq 1}$?

Comment: You have the right idea, but that looks like $\epsilon$ is a continuous variable or something. Usually you  say let $\epsilon>0$ be fixed; i.e. you think of $\epsilon>0$ as an arbitrary fixed value. I would write as follows: Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. If $0 < \epsilon \le 1$, then . . . (your OP argument here). If $\epsilon>1$, $P(|X_{(n)}-1| \ge \epsilon)$ is trivially zero since $|X_{(n)} -1| = 1- X_{(n)} $ is in $[0,1]$. So in any case, $P(|X_{(n)}-1| \ge \epsilon) \to 0$.

Comment: You could certainly use your indicator notation when $\epsilon$ is fixed.